# Why is the value of TF-IDF different from IDF_?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

Why is the value of the vectorized corpus different from the value obtained through the `idf_` attribute? Should not the `idf_` attribute just return the inverse document frequency (IDF) in the same way it appears in the corpus vectorized?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = ["This is very strange",
          "This is very nice"]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
corpus = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

print(corpus)
```

Corpus vectorized:

```
  (0, 2)    0.6300993445179441
  (0, 4)    0.44832087319911734
  (0, 0)    0.44832087319911734
  (0, 3)    0.44832087319911734
  (1, 1)    0.6300993445179441
  (1, 4)    0.44832087319911734
  (1, 0)    0.44832087319911734
  (1, 3)    0.44832087319911734
```

Vocabulary and `idf_` values:

```
print(dict(zip(vectorizer.vocabulary_, vectorizer.idf_)))
```

Output:

```
{'this': 1.0, 
 'is': 1.4054651081081644, 
 'very': 1.4054651081081644, 
 'strange': 1.0, 
 'nice': 1.0}
```

Vocabulary index:

```
print(vectorizer.vocabulary_)
```

Output:

```
{'this': 3, 
 'is': 0, 
 'very': 4, 
 'strange': 2, 
 'nice': 1}
```

Why is the IDF value of the word `this` is `0.44` in the corpus and `1.0` when obtained by `idf_`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of `l2` normalization, which is applied by default in `TfidfVectorizer()`.
If you set the `norm` param as `None`, you will get the same values as `idf_`.

```
>>> vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(norm=None)

#output

  (0, 2)    1.4054651081081644
  (0, 4)    1.0
  (0, 0)    1.0
  (0, 3)    1.0
  (1, 1)    1.4054651081081644
  (1, 4)    1.0
  (1, 0)    1.0
  (1, 3)    1.0
```

Also, your way of computing the feature's corresponding idf values is wrong because `dict` does not preserve the order.

You could use the following method:

```
 >>>> print(dict(zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), vectorizer.idf_)))
      
     {'is': 1.0,
      'nice': 1.4054651081081644, 
      'strange': 1.4054651081081644, 
      'this': 1.0, 
      'very': 1.0}
```